# In PHP 7.0, predefined variables such as "$REQUEST_METHOD" cannot be accessed

Tags: php

I wrote a php file and want to call on `$REQUEST_METHOD` (a predefined variable), but I cannot get the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pre Vars Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo "提交的方法：" .$REQUEST_METHOD;
    echo "<br>网络协议：".$SERVER_PROTOCOL;
    echo "<br>主机名称".$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I checked the `php.ini` file, but I could not find `register_global= On`. So I added this into the `php.ini` file, however, it still does not work. My php version is `7.0.8`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you exclude the Chinese characters?

Comment: What happens when you echo out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`?

Comment: Thank you. I get it. $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] should be used instead of $REQUEST_METHOD. Thank you very much. @Franker

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess only these are the predifined variables.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php.
[image]

And you may take a look at `$_SERVER`, it has what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call just `$REQUEST_METHOD`, something like that doesn't exist.

You actually need $_SERVER and then ask for REQUEST_METHOD, like:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it.